# How to get an input from a base template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to have a little text area in which people can write something and immediately post it to the database. So, I need a way to manage an input from a base template. I know how to do this with normal templates, but I can't figure out how to do it with the base template without writing the same process in every child template of my project.

I have already heard of template processors, but my problem is that I don't want to pass a variable to the base template, but to take it from the base template.

This is the piece of code that is placed in the base template. I need to access the user's input in the textarea and post it to the database.

```
        <form method="POST">
            <textarea id="comment" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea> <br>
            <button type="submit">Send message</button>
        </form>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you include some code that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have included the form that would be placed in the parent template, I hope it helps.

Comment: so you just want to save your form?

Comment: Yes, it was just that. After more searches on the Internet I finally set up a view that managed the post action and redirected to the previous page with request.META.HTTP_REFERER. Thank you very much for your time though.